# How to intercept and change exception in Scala Akka in play framework 2.4.6

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

Actor (**OrgaActor**) asks a database actor (**DbActor**) for a document. The **DbActor** does not always deliver a document, but also a database error exception. The **OrgaActor** shall now alter the received exception with details (that it is actually an Organization query, not a generic database query). I struggle to intercept the exception from **DbActor** and change it in the result sent to the controller (**OrgaCtl**). Non working sample code of **OrgaActor**

```
def receive = {
    case GetDocument(id: String) => {
      try {
        val answer = (dbActor ? DbActor.GetDocument("Orga", id)).mapTo[JsValue]
        play.Logger.debug("in answer")
        answer.pipeTo(sender())
      } catch {
        case e: Exception =>
          play.Logger.debug("in exception")
          val fhe = error.FhException(e, 404, error.Error.ORGA_LOAD, "error on load " + id)
          sender() ! akka.actor.Status.Failure(fhe)          
    }
}
```

The **DbActor**'s *GetDocument* :

```
case GetDocument(coll: String, id: String) =>
  try {
    val response = new FigureheadDb().get(coll, id)
    sender() ! response.jsonElementPayload()
  } catch {
    case e: Exception =>
      val fhe = error.FhException(e, 404, error.Error.FH_ID, "error on load " + id + " in coll " + coll)
      sender() ! akka.actor.Status.Failure(fhe)
      throw fhe
  }
```

The *inException* debug message is never shown, so I guess the *throw fhe* code in **DbActor** never arrives at the calling **OrgaActor**. The **DbActor** is tied into **OrgaActor** with *val dbActor = context.actorOf(Props[DbActor], name = "db-actor")*.

The question is: How can I intercept the error thrown by the database actor in the organization actor and deliver the enriched error to the global error handler? Currently the global error handler always gets the database actor error.

**Code based on accepted Answer**

**dbActor**:

```
case GetDocument(coll: String, id: String, originalSender: ActorRef) =>
  try {
    val response = new FigureheadDb().get(coll, id)
    sender() ! GetDocumentSuccess(response.jsonElementPayload(), originalSender)
  } catch {
    case e: Exception =>
      val fhe = error.FhException(e, 404, error.Error.FH_ID, "error on load " + id + " in coll " + coll)
      sender() ! GetDocumentFailed(fhe, id, originalSender)
  }
```

**OrgaActor**:

```
case GetDocument(id: String) => {
    val answer : Future[Any] = dbActor ? DbActor.GetDocument(coll, id, sender())
    answer.map {
      case success: DbActor.GetDocumentSuccess => 
        play.Logger.debug("in success")
        success.originalSender ! success.result.as[JsValue]
      case failure: DbActor.GetDocumentFailed => {
        play.Logger.debug("in failure")
        val fhe = error.FhException(failure.cause, 404, error.Error.ORGA_LOAD, "error on load " + failure.id)
        failure.originalSender ! akka.actor.Status.Failure(fhe)
      }
      case any => {
        play.Logger.error("Dead end")
      }
    }
}
```

**object DbActor**:

```
  case class GetDocument(coll: String, id: String,  originalSender: ActorRef)
  // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35549414/how-to-intercept-and-change-exception-in-scala-akka-in-play-framework-2-4-6
  sealed trait GetDocumentResult
  case class GetDocumentSuccess(result: JsValue, originalSender: ActorRef) extends GetDocumentResult
  case class GetDocumentFailed(cause: Exception, id: String, originalSender: ActorRef) extends GetDocumentResult
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `OrgaActor` you try to catch an exeption which is never thrown.

The code below is quoted from your question, however I included a type annotation for `answer`.

```
try {
    val answer: Future[JsValue] = (dbActor ? DbActor.GetDocument("Orga", id)).mapTo[JsValue]
    play.Logger.debug("in answer")
    answer.pipeTo(sender())
  } catch { ... }
```

You would probably expect the second line (`val answer ....`) to throw an exception, however it will not throw an exception, but a Future is returned, which might succeed or fail.

Using `answer.pipeTo(sender())` the result of the future (which could be a `Status.Failure`) is sent to the sender().

As a solution you can define a sealed trait `GetDocumentResult` which two case classes implementing the trait:

```
// you already have this case class, I added the original sender,
// since you might need this information to know where to send the final result
case class GetDocument(coll: String, id: String, originalSender: ActorRef)

sealed trait GetDocumentResult
case class GetDocumentSuccess(result: JsValue, originalSender: ActorRef) extends GetDocumentResult
case class GetDocumentFailed(cause: Exception, id: String, originalSender: ActorRef) extends GetDocumentResult
```

Using this your `DbActor` can send either a `GetDocumentSuccess` or a `GetDocumentFailed` as a response to the `OrgaActor`. And once the `OrgaActor` receives the response, it can send the final result (either the success, or the postproccessed failure message) to the original sender.